# Guzzle + Empty response

Tags: drupal, guzzle

I use Guzzle to consume data from an external WS. But, I'm encountering a problem to get the data.

```
$body = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

With the above code, I get an empty response.

If I convert the body to a stream and use this code:

```
$body = $response->getBody();
$stream = Psr7\stream_for($body);
$results = $stream->read(1024);
```

I get data but these data are truncated (1024 characters).

Why the first code didn't return any data? Is there a solution to add an "unlimited" option for the '->read' function?

I have tested many solutions, without success:

```
$response->getBody()->rewind();
$response->getBody()->__toString();
(string) $response->getBody()...
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours and many many posts.... I found the solution.

The WS is built on a windows server. So, I need to modify the encodage of these datas with this code :

```
$response = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $response);
```

And now it's ok, I get the results.